# Visual Studio Code: Отладчик недоступен, не удается отправить "variables"

Tags: javascript, консоль, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, отладка

**Отладчик недоступен, не удается отправить "variables".**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне хотелось бы не обращаться к браузеру каждый раз, когда нужно посмотреть массив, а делать все в VSC.

Вот пример моего кода:

```
let a = [];
for (let i = 0, c = 2; i < 4; c += 2, i++) {
    a[i] = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        a[i][j] = c;
    }
}
console.log(a);
```

Резюме:
В хроме отладчик показывает всё отлично, что видно на скриншоте. Как сделать также или подобно отладчику хрома но только в Visual Studio Code консоли отладки.
Спасибо.

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

launch.json

допишите `"outputCapture": "std"`.
мне помогло.

вот пример моего:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "outputCapture": "std",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\callstack\\app.js"
        }
    ],
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio Code: Отладчик недоступен, не удается отправить "variables" [РЕШЕНО]
Как говорится :)

Спасибо Павел!

Тольи все такие умные и как то сами решают этот вопрос, то ли производят отладку другими средствами, из коробки на сколько я понимаю, данный отладчик работает так как я показывал на скриншоте. 

Примерно 2 года, время от времени пытался решить эту свою проблему. Уже научился использовать другие отладчики, которые также показывают массив в консоли VSC. Но теперь уже наверное буду пользоваться старым методом. 

Ваш ответ был очень полезен. Спасибо!